# How to catch invalid url error in got module get stream?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to using got module to get a file from a given url, but when the url is invalid, i can't catch the error with the error handler.

My code:

```
got.stream('https://google.com').on('error', error =>
        {
            console.log('error!!!')
        })
```

Comment: Since the given url is valid, it doesn't throw any error. Try some invalid url, it works. So, your code is correct.

Comment: ```node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);``` this is what happened, it isn't work

Comment: For me it is working fine. I changed the url to gogle.com. This is the error am getting `GotError [RequestError]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: gogle.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:www.google.com`